# PHP SDK - Facebook Logout

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, logout

I am using the latest version of PHP SDK for Facebook (3.2.1)

I was wondering, when logging out using the function provided in `base_facebook.php` from the sdk, if there was a way to stop it from actually logging out of facebook, but still deleting the session for the website application?

Below is the logout function from `base_facebook.php`

```
/**
* Get a Logout URL suitable for use with redirects.
*
* The parameters:
* - next: the url to go to after a successful logout
*
* @param array $params Provide custom parameters
* @return string The URL for the logout flow
*/

 public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
 session_destroy();
 return $this->getUrl(
  'www',
  'logout.php',
 array_merge(array(
  'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl(),
  'access_token' => $this->getUserAccessToken(),
  ), $params)
 );
}
```

and then my logout url is: `$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();`then obviously using a anchor tag to logout: `<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>`

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont use $logoutUrl.

```
 <li><a href="?action=logout">Logout</a></li>
```

And in your php code add this. This will only logout you from your app .

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
        $facebook->destroySession();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I was just going to use session_destroy(); but that seemed to log out of facebook too, this works though, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a file logout.php

```
<?php 
session_start();            //start session
$_SESSION = array();    //clear session array
session_destroy();      //destroy session
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Log Out</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>You have successfully logged out!</p>
<p>Return to the <a href="....index.php">Home</a> page</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And change your code where you check user status

```
if ($user) { 
    $params = array( 'next' => 'http://....../logout.php' );
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Use $logoutUrl for logout the user.

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
<?php echo "Welcome, ".$me['first_name']. " " .$me['last_name']   ." <br />";
      echo "Id: " . $me['id'] ." <br />";  ?>

<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">  Logout </a> <br />

<?php else: ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"> 

   <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif"> </a>  
 <?php endif ?>
```

Hope it will work fine