# facebook logout only doing logout from website not from the facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am doing the facebook login and logout from a website. So if a user wants to login into the site he will click on facebook login and when he will click on logout then he will automatically logout from both facebook and from the site as well. So all for that I have made my code like this
In index.html my code is like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
     channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
     status     : true, // check login status
     cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
     xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
   });
};
// logs the user in the application and facebook
function login(){
FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
     if(r.status === 'connected'){
            window.location.href = 'fbconnect.php';
     }else{
        FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
              //if (response.perms)
                    window.location.href = 'fbconnect.php';
            } else {
              // user is not logged in
            }
     },{scope:'email'}); // which data to access from user profile
 }
});
}

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';                
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

//]]>
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='login();'>Facebook Login</a>
```

and in fbconnect.php my code is like this

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    //echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>login</a>";

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    //echo $loginUrl; 
    if($user){
        $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user; 
        $_SESSION['user_pro']= $facebook->api('/me');
        echo $_SESSION['user_pro']['first_name'];
        echo $_SESSION['user_pro']['last_name'];
        echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($_SESSION);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'not logged in '; 
    }
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>log out </a>"
?>
```

and in logout.php my code looks like this

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';    //including the facebook php sdk
$facebook = new Facebook();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$url = 'index.html';
$facebook->destroySession();
session_destroy();
header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

All this is doing the site logout but it is not doing the logout from facebook. So can someone kindly tell me how to do logout from both facebook and website at a same time? Any help and suggestions will be reallly appreciale. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dont'use any redirect `<a href='logout.php'>log out </a>`

only need on action facebook session destroy

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
        $facebook->destroySession();
    }
```

Then after you can use your site session destroy
For more info :- [PHP SDK - Facebook Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931402/php-sdk-facebook-logout)

Comment: Nope..this one is no working .. I tried the code in logout.php like this
`<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';    //including the facebook php sdk
$facebook = new Facebook();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$url = 'index.html';
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
        $facebook->destroySession();
    }
header('Location: '.$url);

?>`

Comment: please try to use on same file not to other file include or redirect

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will not do logout from Facebook.

I see you are using the JS SDK also so you need to use JS API for logout. You can do as

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick = "fb_logout();" >Logout </a>';
```

You need to add the following JS function, I see u already have FB.login

```
<script>
            function fb_logout(){
                    if (FB.getAuthResponse()) {
                        FB.logout(function(){
                            top.location.href = 'logout.php'
                        });
                    }else{  
                        top.location.href = 'logout.php'
                    }
            }
</script>
```

Make sure you have the following JS in fbconnect.php file so as to trigger the FB functions
So the complete code is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID ; ?>', status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

function fb_logout(){
                        if (FB.getAuthResponse()) {
                            FB.logout(function(){
                                top.location.href = 'logout.php'
                            });
                        }else{  
                            top.location.href = 'logout.php'
                        }
                }
</script>
```

In the file `logout.php` you can handle the logout code for your website.

Also for generating the logout using the PHP SDK you need to do as

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'page after logout' );

$logouturl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.

<a href="<?php echo $logouturl; ?>"> Logout </a>
```

I would suggest to use JS SDK for logout it works for sure and it logs out from Facebook as well.

Comment: I tried your code. But in browser console panel I am getting error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined`

Comment: hmm looks like u did not add the JS code on fbconnect.php. I have updated the answer.

Comment: still its showing the error in console panel like 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined`
Can you edit your answer with my all code.

Comment: DId u add <div id="fb-root"></div> above the JS this is needed to initialize the FB.

Comment: Ok..finally that worked. But here another question comes. Lets say I have made login from the website and in another tab I have opened facebook and made logout from the another tab. Again when I came to my site facebook login and made referesh the page then it showed me error like Fatal `error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in src/base_facebook.php on line 1340.` Now how to solve this one.

Comment: I suppose you are refreshing fbconnet.php page and yes you will get this message. To get rid of this you need to add the code to see if the user is logged in using event subscribe You can check here http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/

Comment: Or the best thing in PHP to use try - catch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48029/discussion-between-newuser-and-abhik-chakraborty)