# Facebook PHP SDK v5 logout in both web application and Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, logout

I am using Facebook SDK v5. Here i am after login, i can get user's data but after that i try to **logout user from my web application as well as Facebook** that is not working.

Here is my code.

```
$a = $this->helper->getLogoutUrl($this->session>userdata('facebook_access_token'),site_url());
    $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
    foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
            $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
        }
    }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    header("Location:" . $a);
```

here `$a` return url.

like this 
`https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[redirect_uri]&access_token[access_token]`

but 
Session destroy in my application so user logout in my application but not logout from Facebook.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483594/how-to-log-out-user-using-facebook-sdk check answers .. they have dealt there something to logout from facebook as well.

Comment: check this thread as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925769/facebook-logout-only-doing-logout-from-website-not-from-the-facebook

Comment: here in my case at logout stage $this->helper->getAccessToken(); is return NULL So i use accessToken from session @Mit.agile